# How to remove "other user" installable trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Is there anyway to delete "other user" installable triggers? Being lucky enough to guess which user to delete only shows their trigger as disabled but still requires you log in their gmail to delete it which is kind of concerning when you are the "owner" of the spreadsheet?

Comment: [view only spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fU3ByF0NvNbfXvZqRt23xJSS7EAkNhinXB5iZH2qEhE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Tedinoz I see the issue, I need a way to get the script.google.com/d/ID associated with the spreadsheet which I am not sure if it is possible to get without first having edit access for a minute... for example if I save the link to the script editor and then you revoke my permission to view only it will let me go back to it with "read only" mode, but I need to figure out a way to get the app script link associated with the spreadsheet... I suspect that if you gave me the link to the app script associated with that project I can install a trigger but I don't have a link in the tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete other user's trigger. A trigger to a script is associated with a user's  Google account (and the script project).

What they do with their trigger is their own business. As  the owner, you can decide if a user has  the privilege to edit/view your spreadsheet. If a user has  been provided with edit access, He can choose to use that  privilege any way he sees fit.  For example, He can choose to respond to any edit made to the sheet manually or programmatically through a script at his disposal.

If you want to know who made a particular edit, you can see the edit history of each cell.

Comment: If you give someone edit permission for one second they retain permanent access to install triggers with any of your functions even if you give them View only access, explain to me how that makes sense, it's my business because their installed trigger can cause everything to execute code onOpen or even onEdit which is insane! Their trigger is installed to my spreadsheet, how does it make ANY sense that I can't disconnect their installed trigger from my spreadsheet? If I give 100 users edit access and all 100 install a trigger, how am I supposed to disconnect those triggers... log in every mail

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the trigger is their own business because it causes it to run on my spreadsheet for ALL users even though they have only view only access..... and even upon removing them from the project entirely they still get to spam the list of triggers with a "temporary" disabled... literally if there is no solution to this you could denial of service spreadsheets very easily.

Comment: @CodeCamper Trigger is not the issue. If you give edit privileges, they can use that privilege. *their installed trigger can cause everything to execute code onOpen or even onEdit*. Without you providing explicit edit permission, their script can't do anything at all and it runs as"them" not as the "current user". *even upon removing them from the project entirely they still get to spam the list..with a "temporary" disabled* It's permanent unless you restore their permissions. And you could easily filter the list of triggers. Until recently you were not even able to see  other user's triggers.

Comment: @CodeCamper Also, you can easily delete the current project within the spreadsheet and make a new bound project(maybe a exact replica of current one).  Alternatively, a simple renaming of the function will prevent the function running on triggers. Think about it... the triggers runs as them -if the script originally had email permissions -All you have to do is change the script to read all their email and send it to you. It's a security issue for them-not you.

Comment: Well you are right about it being a security issue for them, but if you have intricate functions that mess with the sheet itself they could add it to OnEdit inappropriately even though they only have View only permissions! How would you create an exact replica of a app script project that is bound to a google sheet? Maybe a step by step process to purge all the triggers would be an acceptable answer to the problem. Is it possible to copy the app script project and delete it and reapply it without needing to mess with copying the entire sheet?

Comment: @Code If they only have view permissions, their script(acting as them) cannot edit the sheet because neither they nor their script will have necessary permissions to edit the sheet. Long way to create a new project: In the script editor, File>New> Project and copy/paste each file in the current file to new project> Delete old project>File> Delete project. Short way is to use [tag:clasp] >`clasp pull`> delete clasp json>`clasp create --parentid "spreadsheetid"`>`clasp push`

Comment: I haven't tested it thoroughly but someone with read only permissions can run a script that forever locks you in a alert box... for example...

Comment: @Code That would be impossible and would be classified as a severe security violation, if possible. The installable trigger runs a specific function as the user, who created the trigger:  the script impersonates the user who created the trigger; if the user can't do something manually, it cannot be done programmatically by the user either. Provide [mre] if you think I'm wrong

Comment: It is very possible, just create a function to loop an alert box and install it OnOpen to the owners spreadsheet, then when the owner sets you to View Only permission your function still continues to spam the owner.

Comment: The reason why this occurs is because SpreadsheetApp always runs as the local user even though it is an installed trigger which has been a glitch for years, so you can also delete everything from the spreadsheet if the person who is forced into running the script has permission to do so. I guess the moral of the story is google sheets is not something you can use with lots of people but only small trusted teams.

Comment: @Code No. `SpreadsheetApp` runs as the user who created the trigger always. No exceptions. But, it seems view-only users have privileges to access `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().` and thus show the alert box. But, even though they can view the script, they can't edit the script in the script editor and it's easy to change the script to anything else by the owner/any other editors. But, like i said, easiest way is to delete the current project and make a new project.

Comment: You know what is weird, when in View only mode the trigger executions do not show up on your dashboard but only the owner of the spreadsheet... even though they are in fact executing. Also it doesn't seem to execute at all for the View only user... if you have a project utilizing the Ui extensively this could easily be exploited by a View only user. But you are right just delete and create a new project. But it stinks if you have hundreds of code containers...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove other users triggers.

Triggers are associated with the Apps Script project, not to the Spreadsheet file.

Users are able to create Apps Script Projects on any spreadsheets they have Edit access to.

If you do not want users creating Apps Script Projects on your spreadsheets, give them Read-Only Access.

The spreadsheets that already have other users triggers on them can only be "purged" by removing access.

Comment: I'm not sure that this addresses the OP's question. "Is there anyway to delete "other user" installable triggers?"

Comment: @ZektorH removing user access entirely still does not delete the trigger it only temporarily disables it, which is a problem anyway because if you have 100 emails how do you know which one is "other user" of the hundreds of "other user"

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently delete a script with all of its installable triggers after making a clean copy of it.

1. Go to the Overview section in the new Apps Script editor.
2. Click the 'Make a copy' button.
3. A new browser tab will be created with the new script on screen, then click the 'Delete project' button in the old script.

You can now add the triggers you need manually or by code.